# JavaScript library for turning dust into text (the reverse effect of Thanos' snap)

Tags: library, javascript, animation

I have found libraries of turning images and text into dust, like how Thanos turns half of the mankind into dust in Avengers. However, I am looking for a library that turns dust into text, which is doing something completely in reverse.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the implementation made here

Source code: https://github.com/amoldalwai/Thanos-Snap-Effect

Demo Link: https://amoldalwai.github.io/Thanos-Snap-Effect/